# Lightning Single Page Application Routing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I'm accustomed to using JavaScript frameworks like AngularJS or Backbone. I've been digging into Lightning/Aura and am trying to understand how I would handle a few fundamental SPA principles using this framework. I've reviewed the developer guide and have the following questions:

1. How would I handle routing in a Lightning app?
2. What would be the equivalent of a route "partial" in a Lightning app? For example, Angular allows me to break out separate HTML partials and load them into the view.
3. How would I maintain state across various routes?
4. What event would I latch onto that would be the equivalent of DOMContentLoaded (document ready)? My assumption would be to listen for aura:doneRendering but I'm actually having some trouble getting my controller to respond to this specific event.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no easy way to do this. We internally have navigateToComponent that allows us to go from one component to another (where each component can act as a view) but this function is not public yet.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected. Similar to what you're describing with navigateToComponent, I'll attempt to devise a solution that uses separate components (with nested components) as routes. I'll post back if/when I'm successful.